# How to extract paragraph text in python using lxml from html file?

Tags: python, html, lxml.html

I am trying to extract the paragraph but getting `[<Element p at 0x7f8c81a26548>]`instead of the paragraph. How can I extract the paragraph?

```css
Selector_1 = "div.bloco-imovel-texto p"
tree.cssselect(Selector_1)
```

```html
<div class="bloco-imovel-texto">
  <h3 class="lbl_description">
    Description </h3>
  <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
    animi, id est laborum et dolorum fugaEt harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est,
    omnis dolor repellendus.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be

```
tree.cssselect(Selector_1)[0].text
```